# Failed to download the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

Tags: osx, macintosh

I am unable to run HTTPS recording in Jmeter. I have used "jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf" for the setup. The Jmeter version is 2.11 and Java jdk7. But I am unable to generate the certificate.

The following error is displayed when running "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder"-
[image: Warning message]

> Could not create script recording proxy - see log for details:'keytool -genkeypair -alias :root_ca:dname "CN-_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (Jmeter root CA, OU=Username: shreesha, C-US' -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass (redacted) -keypas (redacted) -validity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1 Illegal option: -ext
>   Try keytool -help

Comment: From the message you should not use -ext as it is an invalid option. If that is specified in the .pdf, that guide is outdated, or your software is. For what versions is the guide valid? (and if not specified, throw that guide away).

Comment: you should ask to move this question to superuser or mac asking different, because it's not related to linux but only to the usage of JMeter

Comment: IMO this Q is on-topic here, so it can stay. True it overlaps ServerFault & SuperUser but it's appropriate here too.